# Can't update the font size in react using tailwindcss library

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a component that has a default font-size(**rem**) and also the component accepts other classes as props.

**the problem is the component has default font-size class:**

```
.text-base{font-size: 1rem}
```

and I want to have more control over the component by passing classes as props with smaller font-size but the default font-size doesn't allow.

**The component:**

```
<Info className="text-sm">Test component</Info>
```

**code inside the component:**

```
const Info = ({ children, className = "" }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={cn("flex p-4 text-base grey", {
        [className]: className
      })}
    >
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-ebwni?file=/src/Info.js

Thanks

Comment: try something like this: https://imgur.com/a/xWvGHrw

Comment: thanks but still not working @ArturCapraro

Answer (score 0):

What you wanted is whenever you create a new "Info" component get it with a "text-base" that represents font-size of 1rem as tailwindcss documentation shows here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-size

so what I did was that I removed "text-base" from className and create a new state using useState hooks that will be updated only if the passed props className from the Info component does not include "text" string inside it which means that the created component is without a font size initialization so in that case initialize to "text-base" so the code will be as the following:

```
import cn from "classnames";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Info = ({ children, className = "" }) => {
  const [baseClass, setBaseClass] = useState("");
  const checkText = () => {
    if (!className.includes("text")) {
      setBaseClass("text-base");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkText();
  });
  return (
    <div
      className={cn(
        "flex p-4 grey",
        {
          [className]: className
        },
        {
          [baseClass]: baseClass
        }
      )}
    >
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Info;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-5807v?file=/src/Info.js